# PHP & cURL - GitHub API - 403

Tags: php, curl, github-api

I'm completely new to cURL and API's, but i'm attempting to build an application that uses [GitHubs Code Search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-code).

in my XAMPP Shell, I can execute the below string with no problems

`curl -u myuser https://api.github.com/search/code?q=XXX+language:XXX?access_token=XXX`

Now, as i'm trying to use cURL in PHP i run into some problems, my code below:

```
$url = 'https://api.github.com/search/code?q=' . $term . 'language:' . $lang . 'stars:' . $stars . '?access_token=' . $token;
$cInit = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cInit, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cInit, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // 1 = TRUE
curl_setopt($cInit, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($cInit, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ':' . $pwd);

$output = curl_exec($cInit);
$info = curl_getinfo($cInit, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$result = json_decode($output);

curl_close($cInit);
```

When i `var_dump($result);` The page greets me with a null value
I checked the HTTP_CODE with the below code:

```
$info = curl_getinfo($cInit, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
var_dump($info);
```

Which then tells me `int(403)` which is `403 Forbidden` which relates to something authentication related. What exactly am i doing wrong in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some little debugging would’ve pointed it out.

If you don't send a user agent then you will get a 403 error, outputting `$output` yields:

> Request forbidden by administrative rules. Please make sure your
> request has a User-Agent header
> (http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required). Check
> https://developer.github.com for other possible causes.

A quick look at the docs your also sending `access_token` which is not required, as your using auth basic.

Ive changed the url and the following works fine:

```
<?php
$user = 'Your Github Username';
$pwd = 'Your Github Password';

$url = 'https://api.github.com/search/code?q=addClass+in:file+language:js+repo:jquery/jquery';
$cInit = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cInit, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cInit, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // 1 = TRUE
curl_setopt($cInit, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($cInit, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($cInit, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ':' . $pwd);

$output = curl_exec($cInit);

$info = curl_getinfo($cInit, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$result = json_decode($output);

curl_close($cInit);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($result, true).'</pre>';
```

**Result:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [total_count] => 8
    [incomplete_results] => 
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => classes.js
                    [path] => src/attributes/classes.js
                    [sha] => 0c90a8dffdb95ec4678f18e07623f9d111c32540
                    [url] => https://api.github.com/repositories/167174/contents/src/attributes/classes.js?ref=3d732cca6b5076a9d13eee98e2b075b37384cd91
                    [git_url] => https://api.github.com/repositories/167174/git/blobs/0c90a8dffdb95ec4678f18e07623f9d111c32540
                    [html_url] => https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3d732cca6b5076a9d13eee98e2b075b37384cd91/src/attributes/classes.js
                    [repository] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 167174
                            [name] => jquery
                            [full_name] => jquery/jquery
                            [owner] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [login] => jquery
                                    [id] => 70142
                                    [avatar_url] => https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/70142?v=4
                                    [gravatar_id] => 
                                    [url] => https://api.github.com/users/jquery
                                    [html_url] => https://github.com/jquery
                                    [followers_url] => https://api.github.com/users/jquery/followers
                                    [following_url] => https://api.github.com/users/jquery/following{/other_user}
                                    [gists_url] => https://api.github.com/users/jquery/gists{/gist_id}
                                    [starred_url] => https://api.github.com/users/jquery/starred{/owner}{/repo}
                                    [subscriptions_url] => https://api.github.com/users/jquery/subscriptions
                                    [organizations_url] => https://api.github.com/users/jquery/orgs
                                    [repos_url] => https://api.github.com/users/jquery/repos
                                    [events_url] => https://api.github.com/users/jquery/events{/privacy}
                                    [received_events_url] => https://api.github.com/users/jquery/received_events
                                    [type] => Organization
                                    [site_admin] => 
                                )

                            [private] => 
                            [html_url] => https://github.com/jquery/jquery
                            [description] => jQuery JavaScript Library
                            [fork] => 
                            [url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery
                            [forks_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/forks
                            [keys_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/keys{/key_id}
                            [collaborators_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/collaborators{/collaborator}
                            [teams_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/teams
                            [hooks_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/hooks
                            [issue_events_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/issues/events{/number}
                            [events_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/events
                            [assignees_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/assignees{/user}
                            [branches_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/branches{/branch}
                            [tags_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/tags
                            [blobs_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/git/blobs{/sha}
                            [git_tags_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/git/tags{/sha}
                            [git_refs_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/git/refs{/sha}
                            [trees_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/git/trees{/sha}
                            [statuses_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/statuses/{sha}
                            [languages_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/languages
                            [stargazers_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/stargazers
                            [contributors_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/contributors
                            [subscribers_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/subscribers
                            [subscription_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/subscription
                            [commits_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/commits{/sha}
                            [git_commits_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/git/commits{/sha}
                            [comments_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/comments{/number}
                            [issue_comment_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/issues/comments{/number}
                            [contents_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/contents/{+path}
                            [compare_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/compare/{base}...{head}
                            [merges_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/merges
                            [archive_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/{archive_format}{/ref}
                            [downloads_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/downloads
                            [issues_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/issues{/number}
                            [pulls_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/pulls{/number}
                            [milestones_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/milestones{/number}
                            [notifications_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/notifications{?since,all,participating}
                            [labels_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/labels{/name}
                            [releases_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/releases{/id}
                            [deployments_url] => https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/deployments
                        )

                    [score] => 0.5187095
                )
//.. snip
```

Comment: All i was missing was useragent? Wow. Guess i have more reading to do.

Comment: Using cURL on the command line will use a default valid User Agent. [PHP has its own value](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.user-agent), which may/may not be set depending on your hosting setup. Easy to miss. Also, you were trying to `json_decode` a non-JSON value, hence the `null` result and why you missed the error message.

Comment: No its all good, it doesn't say it specifically on the docs, but off somewhere else, easily missed. When a response don't json_decode dump it to screen, though you would think the response would of been in json, not plaintext lol